# AWK: Compare two files, match fields 1 and 2, take value from file2 and add to last field of field1

Tags: awk

I want to compare the first two fields of two files.  If a match is made, take the 3rd field from file 2 and add it to the last field of file 1. It'd be nice to convert the basic code that I have when using file comparison.

```
awk 'NR==FNR{c[$1$2]++;next};c[$1$2] > 0'
```

**File 1**

```
NODE1   INTERFACE1  515
NODE1   INTERFACE2  511
NODE2   INTERFACE1  261
NODE2   INTERFACE2  51
NODE3   INTERFACE1  725
NODE3   INTERFACE2  611
```

**File 2**

```
NODE1   INTERFACE1  616
NODE1   INTERFACE2  15
NODE2   INTERFACE1  61
NODE2   INTERFACE2  788
NODE3   INTERFACE1  155
NODE3   INTERFACE2  725
```

**New File**

```
NODE1   INTERFACE1  515 616
NODE1   INTERFACE2  511 15
NODE2   INTERFACE1  261 61
NODE2   INTERFACE2  51  788
NODE3   INTERFACE1  725 155
NODE3   INTERFACE1  611 725
```

Comment: and if some lines wouldn't match?

Comment: If no match is made, print "no_match" in the last field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR {c[$1,$2]=$3; next} 
               {print $0, (($1,$2) in c?c[$1,$2]:"no_match")}' file1 file2
```